# Postgres create table from json field

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, object

I have this `json` field in a table A called `foo` (A.foo is `json` data).

All the `foo` values are just arrays of object like `"[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]"`, what I want to do is go through all the `foo` values and generate a table like :

```
a | b
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

where `a` and `b` are the columns and the values are in rows. Any idea on how I can do that? My field is `json` and not `jsonb`

Answer (score 2):

According to [Postgres documents](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) you can use `json_to_recordset` to convert array o object to record set.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2a17248bd32e76aa86feeb01a9e66735)

```sql
select 
  x.a,
  x.b
from 
  json_to_recordset('[{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 3, "b": 4}]')
    as x(a int, b int)
```